# String.match() function returns null even when there is a match

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to match a regex with some data in a file, the match function however returns null even when the match clearly exists in the data.

I have tried same data and regex on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and it shows a match.

following is the code

```
var fs = require('fs');
try {  
    var data = fs.readFileSync('File.txt', 'utf8');
    data = data.toString();
    var regex = /^(hi|hI|Hi|HI)\s[^dD].*?$/gm;
    var result = data.match(regex);
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Error:', e.stack);
}
```

and these are the contents of file

```
Hi Alex how are you doing
hI dave how are you doing
Good by Alex
hidden agenda
Alex greeted Martha by saying Hi Martha
```

I used same data on RegExr and it shows first line as a match. but when I run the above code on my machine the result variable remains null.

is there something that I am missing ?

following are some screen shots while i was debugging the code in vscode.

1. contents of data variable
   [image]
2. state of result variable.
   [image]
3. result of JSON.stringify
   [image]

**Edit. JSON.stringify results**

I ran the program on cmd and shockingly the string has a space in front of it.

Comment: FYI, your regex can also be written as `/^hi\s[^d].*/gmi`

Comment: Your code works fine for me. How do you know that `result` is `null`? Nothing in the code you posted examines the value of `result`. Do you have a `console.log()` in your actual code?

Comment: @nologin that will make absolutely no difference; there's nothing wrong with a regex literal.

Comment: Probably you are loading a wrong file!

Comment: @Pointy I am running the code in debug mode in vscode, and it shows the result as null after the call to match

Comment: @pooyan No, file is correct, I can see the contents of data variable.

Comment: @mightyWOZ, So it is also possible that there is some space at first of the file or there are some Unexpected character(like `tab` or etc. ) in the file.

Comment: Well what if you run it *outside* the IDE?

Comment: @Pointy same result, I changed the code to print the result variable and ran it from cmd, it prints null.

Comment: @pooyan what about quotation marks, strings are contained within quotation marks.

Comment: could you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and tell us what you get? (not a screenshot please)

Comment: Did you save the file with BOM? What is the value of `data.codePointAt(0)`?

Comment: Just glancing at it your strings have leading whitespace you're not accounting for,  but I can't reproduce your issue otherwise.

Comment: The `^` in the pattern means the pattern will match at the *start* of the line. You must have some invisible chars in your string at the start. Either BOM or some chars like `\u200E`

Comment: @JaredSmith but why can't I see that whitespace in VIM

Comment: You may just use `data = data.replace(/^\uFEFF/, '')` to remove the BOM if it is there, and then run your regex. VIM is a text editor, it can handle BOM. Same as Notepad. `readFileSync` leaves BOM in the read data and it is up to the programmer to handle it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it was BOM, but how it got introduced into my file?

Comment: Some file editors suggest a choice "UTF-8 with BOM" on file saving or just have it in the settings as a default option.

Comment: @mightyWOZ It is already there. It was introduced it by someone who saved the file in UTF-8 encoding with BOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been solved with the help of the @vsemozhetbyt's answer and many helpful comments. I am adding this answer to help if anybody encounters the some problem in future.

### why it happened ?

Because of some wrong encoding, in my particular case the File.txt was originally File.jsp and I changed its extension to .txt and saved it.
after this I read the file.txt which contained same text as JSP and did some regex matching, it worked fine and there was no BOM in the file.

Problem appeared when I opened the file in notepad and replaced all its contents with 5 lines of text shown in the question and saved it.

### what is BOM

Read this great [article](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark)

### How I removed BOM

I opened the file in binary mode in vim using

```
vim -b File.txt
```

and removed the first three chars (Bytes)

Answer (score 2):

The space in the JSON output seems to be [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). If so, `data.codePointAt(0)` should be `65279`.

Answer (score 2):

When you read file in with `fs.readFileSync` the BOM is not stripped from the data read and it is up to the programmer to handle it. See [fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8') doesn't strip BOM markers](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1918).

You may just use

```
data = data.replace(/^\uFEFF/, '')
```

This will remove the BOM if it is there, and then you may run your regex.

Note you do not see the BOM when opening text files in text editors, like VIM, Notepad, because they can handle BOM.